# Visual Studio EF: controller thinks its using an old context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The problem is, I have a controller which was using a db context that I needed to replace with just another db context that has the same entities (I commented out or removed the entities in that previous context).

```
    public MyController(MyNewContext myNewContext)
    {
        _context = myNewContext;
    }
```

The issue is, the solution does not build and says "Can't.. convert from MyNewContext to MyOldContext".
It's like Visual Studio keeps remembering the old context's name and despite it being commented out, etc, it still clings to the old name and expects all the stuff to be related to that old context.

I tried to 'break and remake' the code by typing in a space everywhere and deleting that space, and finally I restarted Visual Studio - none of this fixed the problem.

Anyone else have this happen?

Comment: what is the datatype of _context? is it MyNewContext or MyOldContext?

Comment: That error sounds like `_context` is declared as a MyOldContext. It might help to see the exact exception message text.

Comment: It used to be MyOldContext and now it's MyNewContext but the application doesn't get with the times. The exact paraphrased message is "Cannot implicitly convert type '...MyNewContext' to '...MyOldContext'.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man I'm stupid! Sorry and yea I had a dentist surgery today so maybe that's why..
DUH my _context is declared with the old data type!

This is the correct comment answer:
**what is the datatype of _context? is it MyNewContext or MyOldContext? – sam**

and

**That error sounds like _context is declared as a MyOldContext. It might help to see the exact exception message text. – Steve Py**

Comment: Yea, I chalk it up to attempting to program under the influence ;)